# converting windows mobile 6.5 app to windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I have a windows mobile 6.5 app which was built using windows forms and using .net compact framework.  The devices are getting old and we would like to run this application on windows phone devices. what is the best way and easiest way to convert this application. I will be using visual studio 2015. Also this application is quite complex and large so its not an option to start again.

Thanks

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no way for simple conversion of your app. Windows Phone has very little in common with old Windows Mobile. Apps for Windows Phone can be written in C# but they are based on different set of technologies. You need to rewrite your app from scratch. Maybe only some parts of the app (old business logic for example) have chance to be used again.